# Function Returning 1, But Output is Zero?

Tags: python, algorithm, list, sorting, data-structures

I have an unusual case, the function returns zero but when I ran it in a debugger, the above function went to return 1:

```
def solution(A):
    n = range(1, len(A)+1)

    if(len(A)!=len(n)):
        return 0

    s = sorted(A)

    if(s==n):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

y = solution([4, 1, 3, 2])

print(y)
```

Is this some usual behavior in Python?

Comment: " the function returns zero but when I print the output, it prints zero on my system" yes, what's the issue?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I ran it in a debugger, the above function went to return 1...that's why I am asking

Comment: probably because when you debugged it you were using python 2, where `range` is a `list`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre well then downvote is unwarranted because this is a real question highlighting a subtle difference arising due to different python versions... still if it returned 1, it should print 1 unless debugger is running different version than my terminal..

Comment: agreed, and I countered the downvote, but your question is slightly unclear because the title somehow contradicts the first sentence of your question. My advice is: read it again and [edit] it. I've edited it feel free to edit more/revert if you feel it's not right.

Comment: @mourinho: that you ran this in a debugger and you got `1` but without the debugger you got `0` was missing from your question.

Comment: @mourinho: you may want to add how you ran the debugger, because you'll need to fix that so you don't get issues like this in future. You really need to be exact about your Python versions when encountering unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a code would work in python 2, but python 3 `range` doesn't return a `list` but it is kept as a range object where `len` works (and does its best to emulate an actual `list`). But in python 3:

```
>>> range(1,4)
range(1, 4)
>>> list(range(1,4))
[1, 2, 3]
>>> [1,2,3] == range(1,4)
False
>>> list(range(1,4)) == [1,2,3]
True
```

The `list` and `range` types are different and according to the documentation

> Objects of different types, except different numeric types, never compare equal.

to get equality you need to explicitly convert `n` to a list

```
n = list(range(1, len(A)+1))
```

more concise working approach:

```
def solution(A):
    return int(sorted(A) == list(range(1,len(A)+1)))
```

IMHO keeping the `int` conversion isn't required unless you explicitly want to return `0` or `1` instead of natural `False` or `True`

Why you got 1 or 0 depending on your debugging or not is probably because you're using 2 different installs of python, one for debugging, and one for running. I suggest that you get rid of python 2 installation if you already use python 3.

Comment: `sorted` of the input list, but at no moment `n` passes through `sort` so `n` remains a `range` object.

Comment: Ah, yes, I see now.

Comment: that said, the "Objects of different types, except different numeric types, never compare equal." thing is a bit off-putting. `range` emulates a real list so well it's hard to tell the difference.

Comment: Tuples and lists also don't compare equal. Nor do strings and lists and tuples. They are all sequences, just like `range()` is a sequence, so I don't see why `range()` would be an exception here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes, I'm not saying it should. just explaining why OP got caught.